# Connecting to the databases of a MockNetwork in Corda

Tags: corda

Often, when writing a MockNetwork test I want to connect to the databases of the nodes and interactively query them. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

see this class and example

https://gist.github.com/dazraf/01115f0d376647f99e8fc453ba07251c

Essentially starts the H2 TCP server and dumps the jdbc connection strings for each node.

It has a method to block the test whilst you interactively query the DBs